# continue в цикле for in, for of

Tags: javascript

continue работает только в циклах с массивом(for (...)), как сделать continue в цикле с обьектом ? return выйдет с функции, break завершит цикл, а мне нужно перейти на следующую  итерацию в цикле по объекту ?

```
for (key in obj) {
    if (typeof obj[key] == 'function') {
      continue;
    }

    path += '.' + key;

    if (typeof obj[key] == 'string' && obj[key] == this.hash) {
      this.linkToHash.push(path);

      continue;
    }

    if (typeof obj[key] == 'object') {
      this.findHash(obj[key], path);
      path = objPath;
    }
}
```

Comment: Вы прямо таки уверены что Вам нужно писать именно так?

Comment: Нет, предложите свой вариант реализации, простой пример

Comment: Не вижу проблемы с continue и объектом. Приведите пример который может воспроизвести проблему

Comment: суть в том что continue не срабатывает на итерациях по обьекту, цикл просто не видит его и идет дальше

Comment: @KhoteyVitaliy, я как раз и говорю про то, что continue работает именно так как и ожидается. И без [mcve] нельзя сказать _почему не работает именно у тебя_

Comment: Понял в чем проблема, у меня в цикле асинхронная функция, по этому и не работает

Answer (score 1):

```
for (key in obj) {
    if (typeof obj[key] != 'function'){
        path += '.' + key;

        if (typeof obj[key] == 'string' && obj[key] == this.hash) {
          this.linkToHash.push(path);

        }else  if (typeof obj[key] == 'object') {
          this.findHash(obj[key], path);
          path = objPath;
        }
    }
}
```

Версия 2:

```
for (key in obj) {
    switch(typeof obj[key]) {
        case 'function':
        break;
        case 'string':
            if(obj[key] == this.hash)
                this.linkToHash.push(path);
        break;
        case 'object':
            this.findHash(obj[key], path);
            path = objPath;
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: оно то так, но такой код тяжело тестировать ) можно как то без вложеностей обойтись ?

Comment: А код с continue легко тестируется?

Comment: да, один if одни тест

Comment: Добавил ещё вариант